# Run Shell Commands using Java provides problems

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, bash, shell

```
public class RunBashCommand {

    public synchronized boolean RunInBash(String command)   {

        System.out.println("CMD: "+command);

        /*String s; not working this code also
        Process p;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            PrintBufferReader(getError(p));
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        try {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", command).start();
            /*Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", command).start();*/
            PrintBufferReader(getError(p));
            /*p.destroy();*/
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static BufferedReader getOutput(Process p) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    }

    private static BufferedReader getError(Process p) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    }

    private void PrintBufferReader(BufferedReader br) throws IOException    {
        int value = 0;
        String s = "";
        while((value = br.read()) != -1)
        {
           char c = (char)value;
           s = s+c;
        }
        System.out.println("EEEE: "+s);
    }   
}
```

I tried this code, but it did not work.
following output came:

```
CMD: cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/; source init.csh
EEEE: /bin/sh: cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/; source init.csh: No such file or directory

CMD: cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/verif/compile/; make clean; make compile; make elab
EEEE: /bin/sh: cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/verif/compile/; make clean; make compile; make elab: No such file or directory

CMD: sh /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/verif/test_lib/src/apb_test31/runme.csh
EEEE: /bin/sh: sh /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/verif/test_lib/src/apb_test31/runme.csh: No such file or directory
```

can some one help?

Comment: Don't pass your command as an argument to `/bin/sh` (especially for `csh`); `new ProcessBuilder(command)`

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively running:

```
/bin/sh "cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/; source init.csh"
```

When you run /bin/sh this way, it treats its first argument as the name of a file to execute as a shell script. Of course, there's no file named "cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/; source init.csh", so you get an error message.

The correct way to invoke `sh` with a *command* as an argument is like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "cd /home/jeevan/workspace/apb_proj/; source init.csh"
```

Using process builder, you'd do:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command).start();
```

The next problem that you're likely to run into is that it appears that the command you're trying to invoke is a `csh` command, not an `sh` command.  "source" is a csh command, and the file you're trying to source is called "init.csh". So maybe you want to invoke csh instead of sh:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/csh", "-c", command).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split command arguments into separate parameters: not `ProcessBuilder("bin/sh", "cd foo/bar")` but `ProcessBuilder("bin/sh", "cd", "foo/bar")`.

You can't use shell metacharacters (like ";") too. To run multiple commands, you have to start multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your commands into a `List` and pass it as the argument to the `ProcessBuilder`. As an alternative you can start the shell process, get it's `OutputStream` and write commands into this stream to execute them.